# Is three or more OR statement on a single line valid?

Tags: javascript

I have this line of code

```
  var data; 

  if(a) { data=a; }
  else if(b) { data=b; } 
 else if(c) {  data=c; } 
 else if (d) { data=d; }
```

Note that a,b,c,d values can be null ,or numbers  i.e it's dynamic but one of the variables will actually be truthy.

I know about this `data=a||b;`

but i haven't seen people do this:
`var data=a||b||c||d;`

Is this valid in Javascript?

Comment: You can do that ! That is called short circuit mechanism.

Comment: @Harmandeep I learnt a new thing. Thanks

Comment: If `a` through to `d` are all falsy then `data` will be set to `d`, which is different to your if-statement

Comment: @Nick Parsons and Charlie... I get that into my skull. Thanks

Comment: Did you try it first? This seems like the sort of thing you would just try for yourself, why ask a StackOverflow question about it?

Comment: @Adrian it's good to ask from experts, as i have used some code which doesn't work on older browsers or obsolete codes. It's nice i cured my curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that is completely valid. Try it for yourself!

```js
var data, a = null, b = 3, c = null, d = 2; 

data = a || b || c || d

console.log(data)
```